# SQL Count where value pair is unique

Tags: sql

Say my table called fruit is

```
Fruit Store    Date
Apple Walmart  2/26/2020
Apple Walmart  2/14/2020
Apple Shoprite 2/16/2020
Pear Walmart   2/26/2020
```

I am looking to select the following

```
Apple Walmart
Apple Shoprite
Pear Walmart
```

I am thinking I need to use Case statements but I am not exactly sure possibly

```
SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE Fruit & Store distinc
```

Comment: hint `group by` or `distinct` your choice

Comment: Most online SQL tutorials (probably all, but who knows) will give you a) the  information you need to understand how to compose a simple query like this on your own and b) a coding area where you can try your code out through your web browser. You really need a structured learning environment, not a coding Q&A site.

Comment: You don't need case statements. If you just want to display what you have shown above, use `select distinct fruit, store from fruit`. If you want to find the count, then you would need to use `groupby`.

Comment: Simply use `SELECT DISTINCT`... that's what it's there for. (I.e. don't go with that other "hint".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use distinct

```
 SELECT distinct fruit, store 
 FROM fruit
```

Comment: Perfect completely forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Fruit , Store 
FROM fruit 
Group By Fruit , Store